# Searching for events in an iCal formatted file in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to look at only events that apply to today in an iCal file. This is my code:

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime

g = open('reachcalendar.ics','rb')
cal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())

for component in cal.walk():
  if component.name == "VEVENT":
    if component.get('dtstart').date() == datetime.today().date()
      print component.get('summary')
      print component.get('dtstart').dt

g.close()
```

But this is resulting in an invalid syntax:

```
  File "today.py", line 9
    if component.get('dtstart').date() == datetime.today().date()
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `:` at the end of the line:

```
if component.get('dtstart').date() == datetime.today().date():
#                                                        HERE^
```

Aside from that, you probably should not call `datetime.today()` inside the loop, call it before, remember the value and use inside the loop:

```
today = datetime.today().date()
for component in cal.walk():
    if component.name == "VEVENT" and component.get('dtstart').date() == today:
        print component.get('summary')
        print component.get('dtstart').dt
```

Comment: Why is it better to remember it?

Comment: @SimonJGreen for performance reasons - if there is something you can precalculate before the loop - do it.